# Do I necessarily need to write a vertex shader to use geometry instancing?

Tags: opengl, graphics, instancing

I've quickly read the GPU gem about geometry instancing, there are many wordings and I'm not sure I understand it well.

If I understand it well, when you use instancing, if you want to apply transformations to the instanced geometry, the only way to do so is to use a vertex shader, but it doesn't mean it's a requirement, it's only the case if you want to apply transformations.

For example, if I want to put houses, I don't need to use a vertex shader (static batching). If I want several walking robots, I will need a vertex shader.

Is static batching useful ? I mean it can save video memory.

EDIT:

https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Fixed_Function_Pipeline this goes further that what I thought I knew

Comment: Yes, keep in mind that you need vertex shader anyway as far as not using deprecated OpenGL. The difference is when using geometry instancing you need to access `gl_InstanceID` from the vertex shader.

Comment: Vertex shader is a necessary element of every (modern) pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, it is needed since at some moment each object has do differenciate from the other at least by some parameter, in your case the position. So in the VS it adds the $\Delta pos$  it to the final pos.

I found this link useful
http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/opengl/opengl-instancing-demystified-r3226